# cron job command

Tags: php

i set my php file in cron jobs with command /home/findia/public_html/ifs/ifs-admin/reminder_mail.php.

```
 But i am getting mail by cron jobs it contains,
```

/bin/sh: /home/findia/public_html/ifs/ifs-admin/reminder_mail.php: Permission denied

Comment: `cron`, not `corn`! Show the cron record, how do you run the php script?

Comment: haha sry, ok its cron....., i want to my php file by cron jobs how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your cron tab put this command instead:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/findia/public_html/ifs/ifs-admin/reminder_mail.php
```

Assuming your php binary is in `/usr/bin`; change it accordingly, if needed.

Comment: yehhhhhhh its working by 
/usr/bin/php -f /home/findia/public_html/ifs/ifs-admin/reminder_mail.php

Answer (score 1):

I put this line `/usr/bin/curl http://YOURDOMAIN/whmcs/crons/cron.php`
(change YOURDOMAIN for the right domain or IP address) n the crontab file and it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file permissions are set correctly for the user that is executing the cron job.

Comment: i m new to Linux commands so please help me how to set permissions?

Answer (score 0):

php CLI scripts need to be run with /usr/bin/php

so for example, your "cron" entry would be (assuming php exists in /usr/bin)..

[insert frequency of execution here>] `/usr/bin/php /home/findia/public_html/ifs/ifs-admin/reminder_mail.php`